# Average pooling by desired output shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

I have a logic question.

I'm trying to create some sort of version of PyTorch's `nn.functional.avg_pool` function with a slight modification: I want the padding/stride to be chosen dynamically based on the desired size of the output. I have successfully worked this out for a single 1d tensor:

```
def ave_pool(tnsr, reduction, pad_val=0, dim = 1):

    size = len(tnsr)
    if size % reduction != 0:
        padlen = np.ceil(size / reduction) * reduction - size
        fpad, bpad = np.ceil(padlen / 2), np.floor(padlen/2)
        tnsr = F.pad(tnsr, (int(fpad), int(bpad)), "constant", pad_val)
        size += padlen
    group = int(size / reduction)
    return tnsr.reshape((-1, group)).mean(dim = 1)
```

This really works great for a single 1d Tensor. However, I want to apply this idea to "batch" of 1d tensors as they pass through my neural network (essentially 2d input at this point).

```
# This works as expected:
x = torch.tensor([2,3,4,8,9,10]).float()
ave_pool(x, 3)
>>> 
tensor([2.5000, 6.0000, 9.5000])

# But what's the logic to up the dimensions to two?
x = torch.tensor([[2,3,4,8,9,10],
                 [6,7,8,9,19,12]]).float()
ave_pool(x, 3)
>>> 
tensor([ 0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  8.,  9., 10.,  0.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 19., 12.])
```

So, how do I extend the logic of my currently working code to 2d tensors so that the output of the previous code block would be:

```
tensor([[2.5000, 6.0000, 9.5000],
        [ 6.5000,  8.5000, 15.5000]])
```

Obviously this question could apply to TensorFlow tensors or NumPy `ndarray`s in addition to PyTorch Tensors. I work with all three and the logic would probably be about the same.

Comment: [Adaptive pooling](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html)?

Comment: @hkchengrex Oh, works like a charm! Gosh, I can't believe I spent two hours trying to figure out my own way. I suck at googling.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice OpenVino documentation that explains the process for 3D, 4D, 5D tensors but it works exactly the same for 1D and 2D.

https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_ops_pooling_AdaptiveAvgPool_8.html

Alternatively you may also take a look at nn.functional.interpolate which could produce something close to the adaptive average pool